Could a de-commissioned synthetic ammonia plant be adapted for use in removing CO2 from the atmosphere (DAC)?
I was prompted to ask this question by viewing a disused $\ce{NH3}$ plant in the harbour near where I live.
Like many it functioned using a methane feedstock from a natural gas find off the coast. I happen to be a believer in the 'retro' approach to excess $\ce{CO2}$ removal from the air i.e. relying on and making use of existing plant or technology rather than simply scaling up experimental works such as that of Climeworks in Iceland. This approach might be less ruinously expensive in energy terms and have a smaller 'carbon footprint'
Unfortunately my working knowledge of the Haber-Bosch reaction is limited and I am not sure what chemical reactions (if any) could be used with this idea. However,de-commisioned synthetic ammonia  plants of the type I mean do have:

Large mechanised air intakes (for N) and

Pressure vessels capable of sustaining the high temperatures and pressures needed for HB.


Might  chemical engineering, therefore, through 'retro-fitting' be able to make use  of these capabilities for significant $\ce{CO2}$ removal (Direct Air Capture)?

The most efficient use of that energy would likely be to make a greenhouse (and to keep it warm and illuminated in Iceland winters). Though inexpensive low-grade geothermal power (without adding yet more CO2) is available in some regions, the actual amount of CO2 removed would be negligible for any industrial process... such carbon-capture plans are used to justify and even incentivize fossil-fuel use.

Is it Iceland? Lets see an outline for the complete process  before proceeding. If one intends to remove CO2 by a work process [non chemical] possibly the energy would be put to better use by replacing a process that forms CO2. The solution is to stop burning fossil fuels and biologically remove CO2.

To: jimchmst Ireland.I  had thought of the project as providing much-needed encouragement to the DAC movement daunted by the prospect of removing trillions  of atmospheric CO2. We have over a century of  success with HB and the tonnage of another atmospheric constituent (N) removed is similarly  impressive. Of course chasing a molecule which makes. up 3/4 of the atmosphere is much easier than one which is.only 1 molecule in 250!The success of Haber-Bosch however should give us courage to persevere...
